# Why does <pre> text sometimes "lose" its font formatting when the browser tab is left open for a while?

Tags: css, google-chrome, browser

Sometimes when I'm looking at a site with some code blocks, navigate away from that tab for a bit and come back to it, the  formatting appears to be lost.

For example, earlier I was looking at some of the Django documentation:

[image: before]

And then when I left that tab open for a little while, looked at other stuff and then came back to it, this is how it looked:

[image]

Of course, when I refresh the page I get the formatting back so it's not a huge deal, but I'm curious as to why this happens at all.

Note: I use Chrome and haven't tested this out with browsers, so it could "just" be a Chrome issue, but I couldn't find anything when I searched the Chromium bug tracker.

Comment: Pretty sure it's just a Chrome issue. Chrome is known to have lots of problems rendering fonts (as is IE).

Comment: You can try to force reflow on tab focus as a workaround.